# Permission denied to storage/emulated/0 on Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I'm trying to access my application files, but [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) tells me that I don’t have any permission to access the folder on the Device File Explorer:

[image]

Comment: You takk about /storage/emulated/0 but the picture is about /storage/emulated. And why would your application files be there? How did your application files land there?

Comment: I can't access storage/emulated/0 because the permission is denied to storage/emualted/.
My app files are there cause that is the symbolic link to the internal storage

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be normal this message.

Better use the 'self' directory just below it as it will give you all.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand why the permission is denied to storage/emulated. But the self folder has the same content.

Answer (score 0):

Your applications files will be under `data/data/your.package.name` if that's what you are looking for. You can see this [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) for reference.

Comment: Yeah but why I have no permissions for the simbolic link /storage/emulated

Comment: as it is mentioned in the doc that 'Most device data is not visible unless you are using a rooted device or an emulator with a standard Android (AOSP) system image, not one of the Google APIs or Google Play system images'.

Comment: Ankit Kumar how do I do that with Genymotion?